# I want to disable the "contact-form-7" submit button when a user has clicked and want to show the text summary from form field

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

The form when submitting redirects to a new page but when coming back, I want the text summary ( which is data entered in a field from form) or even just "Thanks for Submitting" If I have to explain in plain words.

**Code**

```
<script>
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
  location = 'https://millionairesplus.in/form-submitted/';
}, false );
add_filter( 'wpcf7_form_autocomplete', function ( $autocomplete ) {
    $autocomplete = 'on';
    return $autocomplete;
}, 10, 1 );
</script>

<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['form_submitted']) && $_SESSION['form_submitted'] === true) {
if ($form_submission_successful) {
    $_SESSION['form_submitted'] = true;
    header('Location: payment-page.php');
    exit;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['form_submitted'])) {
    echo '<p>Form already submitted.</p>';
} else {
    <label> First name
        [text* first-name autocomplete:first_name] </label>

     <label> Last name
        [text* last-name autocomplete:last_name] </label>

    <label> Email
        [email* idea-email autocomplete:email] </label>

    <label> Phone 
        [tel* Phone autocomplete:Phone ] </label>

    <label> Startup Name
        [text* startup-name] </label>

    <label> Summary of idea in detail
        [textarea* summary of idea] </label>

    [submit class=cf7-close-form "Submit"]
}
?>
```